# A simpler way for an entropy inequality

Tags: probability-theory, entropy

I have to show that

$\frac {1}{N}H(X_1,...,X_N)\le H(X_1)$.

for a stationary stochastic process.

I know that $H(X_1,...,X_N)=\Sigma _{i=1}^N H(X_i|X_1,...,X_{i-1})$.

So far I have plugged that into the original inequality to find that

$\frac {1}{N}\Sigma _{i=1}^N H(X_i|X_1,...,X_{i-1})=\frac {1}{N}(\Sigma _{i=1}^{N-1} H(X_i|X_1,...,X_{i-1})+H(X_N|X_1,...,X_{N-1}))\le \frac {1}{N}(\Sigma _{i=1}^{N-1} H(X_i|X_1,...,X_{i-1})+H(X_1)$

I have also previously shown that $H(X_N|X_1,...,X_{N-1}))\le H(X_1)$

Should I proceed by induction or can anybody recommended a different way?

Comment: Simply see that $H(X_i\mid X_1,\cdots,\ X_{i-1})\le H(X_1)\implies H(X_1,\cdots,\ X_N)\le NH(X_1)$

Comment: I see the first part of the statement, simply replace i with N.  but are you trying to say that $ H(X_i∣X_1,⋯, X_{i−1})$ plus something is $H(X_1,⋯, X_N)$? Because I understand each part separately, but not together

Comment: Your own proof's first line expresses $H(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ as a sum of $N$ conditional entropies. Samrat's comment just says that each one of those $N$ terms is less than (or equal to) $H(X_1)$ and you are done.